# Fatal error when called with functions in php

Tags: php

hey guys am new to php app development..I have been doing a code witch functions which give me an error output saying

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function baby() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\sample.php on line 11..
```

My code

```
<?php
class something {

function namely($a){
    echo $a;
}
function baby($b){
    echo $b;
}

function getadress() {
    something::namely(1)->baby(2);
}
}

$var = new something;

echo $var->getadress();
```

Since am new to php i dunno if i can call both functions like `something::namely(1)->baby(2);`
Is this valid in php ??..or is it wrong to call both functions together as i mentioned ? ..Hope you can help me ..Thanks

Comment: this is, because `::namely(1)` returns null and when you call `->baby(2)` on null, you're going to get this error

Comment: There is pretty much everything wrong with this  :)  What do you want this little bit of code to do?

Comment: no ..it echos ..$a which is 1 ..i get 1 as output but i didnt get 2 ..means function getadress() is not working

Comment: yes, it echos 1, but it returns null...

Comment: @CullyLarson can i cal like this ?? something::namely(1)->baby(2);..is this wrong way of calling ?

Comment: @user3609223, this would only work, if you return a object of type `something` with the `namely(1)`

Comment: @Dinistro yes it does ..i need to get output like 1,2 ..Is it wrong type of call something::namely(1)->baby(2);..is it allowed in php ??

Comment: That means you're calling baby(2) on the object returned by namely(1).  namely(1) doesn't return anything, so you're getting an error.

Comment: Why mixing `::` and `->`? Are you aware what they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your namely() method doesn't return any value. Change it to this.

```
function namely($a){
    echo $a;
    return $this;
}
```

And now following function will work.

```
function getadress() {
    $this->namely(1)->baby(2);
}

$var = new something();
echo $var->getadress();
```

Answer (score 1):

First you Class shoud Look like this:

```
class something {

    function namely($a){
        echo $a;
        return $this;
    }
    function baby($b){
        echo $b;
        return $this;
    }

    function getadress() {
        this->namely(1)->baby(2);
    }
}
```

Note, that i added "return my self" to your Methods.

The second Part: You need an Object instance:

```
$something= new something();
$something->getadress();
```

Edit: To Slow ;)